# Mapping two mysql table based on email address

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql table

Table 1

```
id email  other fields
```

Table 2

```
id email other fields
```

where id for table1 is `auto increment` mysql column. and in table 2 id is only `primary key not NULL` .

some how the id for table 2 had gone wrong. 
Now both tables are having some records and I want to make id in table 2 same as table 1.

let's take an example

Table 1 have

```
1 a@a.com
2 b@b.com
```

Table 2 have

```
1 b@b.com
2 a@a.com
```

if I fire query

```
update 
  table2 
set 
  id=(select id from table 1 where email="a@a.com") 
where 
  email = "a@a.com"
```

I will get error because table 2 is already having id value of 2. 
now how can I solve this problem ?

I want id of table2 same as table1 based on email.

Comment: Removing the primary key, fixing up the IDs and readding the key is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this :

```
update table2 set email=(
case
when email='b@b.com' Then 'a@a.com'
when email ='a@a.com' Then 'b@b.com'
end)
```

Comment: OP could have dozens records... swapping them with SELECT-CASE is not a solution...

Comment: @Marco In current question the condition is for two records.

Comment: @Downvoter Read the question. he wants swap for two records only not for 1000 records.

Comment: I dont't know, maybe you're right or not. I'm confused because he wrote _let's take an example_ so I think that those two records are not the only ones affected by id problem. What do you think?

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer sorry I have given two records as an example. My table has near about 5000 records.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're doing a one-off fix. Go into phpMyAdmin, or your favourite database editing tool and remove the PK constraint from table2. Fix your records with those queries, then re-add the PK constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @rickythefox told you or you could reach your goal with two queries:

1. Run your query adding to table2.id a fixed quantity to table1.id (e.g. 500.000)
2. Update your table2 with another query subtracting fixed quantity